# C# MAUI Getting NETSDK1094 error when building Release version

Tags: c#, blazor, maui

I am getting the below error when I build Release where I don't have any issue with building Debug version. Any idea?

`Error  NETSDK1094  Unable to optimize assemblies for performance: a valid runtime package was not found. Either set the PublishReadyToRun property to false, or use a supported runtime identifier when publishing. When targeting .NET 6 or higher, make sure to restore packages with the PublishReadyToRun property set to true.    HaruHaru.Components.Blazor  C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.102\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets    299`

Tried rebuilt the entire solution and restored workload but it didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions in the error message?

Comment: I found the same error in the GitHub page: [.NET MAUI Class Library build in the Release config fails to compile for the Windows target whereas Debug config works fine](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12100). You can check it.